# Trouble in Boot Repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had a problem with my grub, it didn't recognize my OS, I have installed windows, ubuntu and kali. But then I tried to use Boot repair in a ubuntu live cd, and then I got to type.

sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda10" apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub*-common grub-common:i386

but when I typed that , a trouble appear that said.

E: Unable to locate package grub-common:i386

then I click forward button , but boor repair didn't let me to go to the next steps.

can u help me to fix this problem ?

thank you so much.

Note: I have a UEFI.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/16121828/

Comment: It sounds like you're running Boot Repair in BIOS mode but you have an EFI-mode installation. Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: All your installs are UEFI, but somehow you installed a BIOS boot grub to MBR. That BIOS grub will not boot. Make sure UEFI/BIOS is set to UEFI boot. Probably with secure boot off. You also really need to houseclean old kernels. Keep a couple but delete all the others.I prefer synatic and keeping 2 kernels, current and one known working older on.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Answer (score 3):

if you're using Ubuntu 64bit. Using the following command (*Change i386 library to amd64*):

`sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda10" apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub*-common grub-common:amd64`

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on oldfred's comment, it does look like you've got EFI-mode installs of both Ubuntu and Windows; however, the Boot Repair message you quote implies that it was running in BIOS mode. Mixing boot modes (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI) is seldom a good idea. In your case, it's best to enter your firmware setup utility and *disable* the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which is what gives EFI firmware the ability to run old BIOS-mode boot loaders. Doing this should reduce the odds of accidentally doing what you seem to have done. An EFI-mode run of Boot Repair *should* complete correctly and get things working. For more on the CSM and how it can cause problems, see [my Web page on the subject.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)